# MySQL - Select all rows where a field value is not unique

Tags: mysql

How can I select all rows in MySQL where a particular field value is not unique. For example I have the following data:

```
---------------------------------------
| ID | Name   |         URL           |
---------------------------------------
| 1  | Store 1| http://www.store1.com |
| 2  | Store 2| http://www.store1.com |
| 3  | Store 3| http://www.store3.com |
| 4  | Store 4| http://www.store4.com |
| 5  | Store 5| http://www.store4.com |
---------------------------------------
```

In this I would want to return the following where the URL field has duplicates:

```
---------------------------------------
| ID | Name   |         URL           |
---------------------------------------
| 1  | Store 1| http://www.store1.com |
| 2  | Store 2| http://www.store1.com |
| 4  | Store 4| http://www.store4.com |
| 5  | Store 5| http://www.store4.com |
---------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want all the original rows, then use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from table t
where exists (select 1 from table t2 where t2.url = t.url and t2.id <> t.id);
```

Answer (score 14):

or, old school...

```
SELECT DISTINCT x.* 
           FROM my_table x 
           JOIN my_table y 
             ON y.url = x.url 
            AND y.id <> x.id 
          ORDER 
             BY id;
```

Comment: Love it! Missed the disctinct at first and was thinking you get more rows, but nope, it's perfect :)

Comment: any idea how the performance of that is against the EXISTS solution? I can guess my sub-select solution would be the slowest

Comment: Love this old school style, making me *think!*  :D

Answer (score 1):

You can inner join to your duplicates.

```
select t.* 
from table t
inner join
(select url from table group by 1 having count(*)>1) duplicates
on duplicates.url=t.url
```